# Forms API #states with multiple radios

Tags: javascript

I've got one `radios` element:

```
$form['trip_radios'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => array(
    'new' => t('Create a new trip'),
    'existing' => t('Use an existing trip'),
  )
);
```

I've got some `#states` prepared:

```
$trip_states = array(
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="trip_radios"]' => array(
      'value' => 'new'
    )
  )
);
```

And some other elements that use `$trip_states` for their `#states`:

```
$form['itinerary_radios'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios',
  '#options' => array(
    'new' => t('Create a new itinerary'),
    'existing' => t('Use an existing itinerary'),
  ),
  '#states' => $trip_states
);

$form['title'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => 'Itinerary name',
  '#required' => FALSE,
  '#states' => $trip_states
);
```

The `title` form element (and many others) properly listens to the `#states` condition and works just fine. However, `itinerary_radios` always shows up no matter what (if anything) is checked on `trip_radios`. Why does a *visible* *condition* on a radios element's **#states** not listen to another radios value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In misc/states.js, it looks for the closest form-item, form-submit, or form-wrapper. Here's the line:

```
$(e.target).closest('.form-item, .form-submit, .form-wrapper').toggle(e.value);
```

This does not play well with the way radios are themed, and states.js does not find anything to toggle. Wrapping the itinerary_name radios in a container and applying #states to the container item is what I would call the quickest workaround.

```
$form['itinerary_radios'] = array(
  '#type' => 'container',
  '#attributes' => array(),
  'radios' => array(
    '#type' => 'radios',
    '#options' => array(
      'new' => t('Create a new itinerary'),
      'existing' => t('Use an existing itinerary'),
    ),
  ),
  '#states' => $trip_states
);
```

Comment: Will it work in a text field?

Comment: I guess another option is to set `'#tree' => TRUE` on a wrapping `#type => 'container'` or fieldset.